# Chrome Extension: Iterate over different pages and collect data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently writing an extension which injects a Content Script. This script parses data from the page, saves it in the localStorage and is able to find the link to the next page and reload via `location.href = "newUrl"`. On this page the script should run again, parse the data, save it, go to the next page etc.

Currently I can't find a solution which lets me do the last part (go to new page, run the script again, go to next page). I can't find a way to do something like "on page loaded execute the parsing function and then execute the goToNextPage function".

Any clues would be highly appreciated!

*(Added from comments)*

My `background.js` includes the following:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "jquery-2.1.3.min.js"}, function () { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"});
  });
});
```

And `content.js` includes some functions to read the "next" link, parse the current page, etc.

Comment: So to make things clear, you don't have a `content_scripts` section in the manifest, you do injection via `executeScript`?

Comment: @Xan, correct. My "background.js" includes the following: 

`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "jquery-2.1.3.min.js"}, function () {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"});
  });
});`

And `content.js` includes some functions to read the "next" link, parse the current page, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would do differently with regards to how you switch pages.

I would message the background with the next URL, and let background update the page and re-inject stuff. This way it will be synchronized with navigation.

```
// Content script
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "updateMe", url: nextUrl});

// Background
function injectScripts(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "jquery-2.1.3.min.js"},
    function () { chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "content.js"}); }
  );
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(message.action == "updateMe") {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: message.url}, injectScripts);
  }
});

// You can use the same handler in onClicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(injectScripts);
```